# Replace selected text with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I am trying to build a specialized WYSIWYG text editor in the browser, and have a very limited set of functionality, but the biggest part of that is wrapping certain text in span tags.

I can find many resources explaining standard stuff (execCommand and whatnot), but have looked and looked and can't find anything to do what I need.

Basically, it's as simple as it sounds: user selects some text, clicks a button or whatever, and the text gets replaced with some other text (the initial case is that same text wrapped in some HTML tags).

I can find ways to do this in a textarea, but I'm just in regular HTML land, with the content in question inside a div with contentEditable marked as true.

I have also found ways to replace all occurences of text, or the first occurence, but not a specific one. Most solutions I find fail when trying to replace anything but the first occurence.

I'm hoping jQuery can do this in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the jQuery [wrapSelection](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/wrapSelection) plugin?

Comment: This does exactly what I want. I don't know how I missed it, but thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740765/how-to-replace-the-currently-selected-text-inside-an-html-textarea). It might help.

Comment: That is all about inside a textarea, which was the problem for me all along (in the sense that I'm not in a textarea).