# Replace text in textarea on his exact position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change some of the text (highlight select) of an textarea on his exact position. For this I use :

```
//Get highlight text 

function hlText () {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("addMess");
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = txtarea.value.substring(start, finish);
    return sel;    
                   }
$("#bla").on("click", function() {

        if($("#addMess").val())
    {

            var highlight = hlText($('textarea#addMess').val());
            var replaceHl = '[]'+ highlight +'[]';
            var selectVal = $('textarea#addMess').val();

            $('textarea#addMess').val(selectVal.replace(highlight, replaceHl));

    }

});
```

The problem is, if the textarea is as follow :

aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa

The replace won't be exact, otherwise if the value highlight is unique, it work.

Thank you.

Comment: Just an heads up. You need not do this -> `$('textarea#addMess').val()` while calling the `hlText()` function.. Since inside `hlText()` you are getting the val using `getElementById` and I think you can use `getSelection()` method instead..

Comment: Thanks, indeed I removed it. Looking for my question with a jquery solution if possible, the other link are in pure javascript.

Comment: Don't use replace, use substrings and rebuild using 3 parts with your start and end values.  beginning + []new text[] + ending

Comment: I done the task with this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/740828/3155987

Here example : http://jsfiddle.net/0vrztjLj/1/ I take any advise for make it better thanks !