# How to replace highlighted word with another value in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, range

I'm creating Google Chrome extension where a user will be able to search for a synonym for a highlighted word inside an editable DOM element such as input, text area. After the extension gives a list of possible results, the user should be able to click on any of them and **only the previously highlighted word** will be replaced by the new value.

However I have problems targeting the exact word that has been highlighted.I tried:

- to use `deepestNode.innerText.replace("old word", "new word");` ,but it replaces any occurrences of the word in the text
- using `Range` interface, but I can't get the values of `startOffset` and `endOffset`, as input node doesn't have `length` property

Can somebody help me find a way to target a word that has been previously highlighted, so that it can be modified.

Comment: How is the word highlighted?  It has to be styled differently than the surrounding text. If the word is in a `span` with a specific `class` or `style`, for example, replace the `innerHTML` of that span.  If the word is no longer highlighted then replacing it may be confusing to the user.

Comment: The word is manually highlighted by the user, but surrounding the word with span containing specific class is a great idea. The only problem is how can I surround the word when it is in input or text area.

Comment: Oh, right. Hmm.  Assuming you're listening for the `select` event (a code snippet would help because I'm guessing at how you're doing this), wouldn't something like this work?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/740828/185034  Both `TextArea` and `Input` have `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much this solved my issue. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your comment, but you saved my day sir!

Comment: That's ok - I'm glad I was able to help.  Considering how much help I've received on SO it's nice to be able to give back.